# In assembly, how can I store esp's address displaced by 4 to a variable?

Tags: assembly

Is it possible to do this? What I want to do is store to for example another register, esi , the address of esp+4 ?

```
mov ecx,[esp+4]
```

From what I understand, the code above does not store the address esp+4 to ecx but rather the value contained in the address of esp+4 right? Im relatively new to Assembly programming so thank you for all those who will be glad to help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`lea` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_153.html) (load effective address).

For example:

```
lea ecx, [esp + 4]
```

You could do this manually like this:

```
mov ecx, esp
add ecx, 4
```

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. Sorry. Doesn't lea load the address that [esp+4] holds? But not the address of esp+4 itself?

Comment: `mov` loads the value stored at address `esp+4`, lea computes what the address `esp+4` would be.